# Update model through UIButton within a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

In `MainVC.swift` I'm capturing the tag of my custom "`PlayerCell`". I want to press the`increaseBtn` (`UIButton`) which will increment the `playerLbl.text` (`UILabel`) by one but also update my model `(PlayerStore.player.playerScore: Int)`

**Main.swift:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PlayerCell", for: indexPath) as? PlayerCell {

        let player = players[indexPath.row]

        cell.updateUI(player: player)

        cell.increaseBtn.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.decreaseBtn.tag = indexPath.row

        return cell

    } else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

}
```

**PlayerCell.swift**

class PlayerCell: UITableViewCell {

```
@IBOutlet weak var playerLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var increaseBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var decreaseBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var scoreLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var cellContentView: UIView!

func updateUI(player: Player){
    playerLbl.text = player.playerName
    scoreLbl.text = "\(player.playerScore)"
    cellContentView.backgroundColor = player.playerColor.color
}

@IBAction func increaseBtnPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let tag  = sender.tag
    // TODO: send this tag back to MainVC?

}
```

Comment: Where is your `playerLbl` and `playerScore`? I don't see it in your code snippet.

Comment: @t4nhpt I updated the PlayerCell code with more of that relevant info. `playerScore` is a property of a Player class, PlayerStore is a class that manages the Player attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the delegate pattern in this case. Create a protocol that Main.swift implements, and that PlayerCell.swift uses as an optional property. So for example:

```
protocol PlayerIncrementor {
    func increment(by: Int)
    func decrement(by: Int)
}
```

Then use an extension on Main.swift to implement this protocol

```
extension Main: PlayerIncrementor {
    func increment(by: int) {
        //not 100% what you wanted to do with the value here, but this is where you would do something - in this case incrementing what was identified as your model
        PlayerStore.player.playerScore += by
    }
}
```

Inside of PlayerCell.swift, add a delegate property and call the delegate increment method in your `@IBAction`

```
class PlayerCell: UITableViewCell {

    var delegate: PlayerIncrementor?

    @IBOutlet weak var increaseBtn: UIButton!

    @IBAction func increaseBtnPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        let tag  = sender.tag

        //call the delegate method with the amount you want to increment
        delegate?.increment(by: tag)    
    }
```

Lastly - to make it all work, assign Main as the delegate to the `PlayerCell UITableViewCell.`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PlayerCell", for: indexPath) as? PlayerCell {

   //self, in this case is Main - which now implements PlayerIncrementor 
   cell.delegate = self

   //etc
```

Comment: So if there are two buttons (one that increments, the other decrements) how  would I add a delegate to PlayerCell?

Comment: @Macness - You can add another method to the protocol - I have updated the example

Comment: @Macness - are there are two buttons on PlayerCell?

Comment: yes and adding the function to the protocol and conforming to that delegate worked! Thank you!